# JS post Object via JSON

Tags: php, json, object, post

I am aware, that there are many questions regarding this topic in general... however, so far I haven't found a solution to my specific problem:

I have objects, looking something like that:

```
var myArray = [];
var ArrayObject = {
    power: 10,
    name: 'arrayobject'
}
myArray.push(ArrayObject);

var myObject = {};
myObject.Name = "test";
myObject.myArray = myArray.slice(0);
```

Now I would like to post this data to php:

```
post("./output.php", myObject,'post');
```

Well, this does not work... I also tried it with

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObject);
```

and on PHP Side with

```
//$myObj = json_decode($_GET['myObject']);
```

but that does not work as well... if I remove the 'myArray' from 'myObject' that works, but having all data in one object would be very nice.

Can anyone tell me how to do that or point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make request like this

```
function test(){

    var myArray = [];
    var ArrayObject = {
        power: 10,
        name: 'arrayobject'
    }
    myArray.push(ArrayObject);

    var myObject = {};
    myObject.Name = "test";
    myObject.myArray = myArray.slice(0);

    jQuery.post('output.php', {
        data: {
            myObject:myObject
        },
    }, function(data) {

        console.log(data);

    });
}
```

then you access the data in PHP like

```
$_POST['data']['myObject']
```

Whole $_POST will look alike

```
array (
    'data' => 
    array (
        'myObject' => 
        array (
            'Name' => 'test',
            'myArray' => 
            array (
                0 => 
                array (
                    'power' => '10',
                    'name' => 'arrayobject',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

You don't need to `json_decode` it automatically does

Comment: Thamaraiselvam, thank you for your fast and extensive reply!
Is it possible, to add two of those objects to data?
data: { myObject:myObject1, myObject2:myObject2}, ... seems not to work...
Additionally: I would like to have the same object in php and tried to do something like $myPHPObject1=$_POST['myObject1']; but that didn't work either. Can you tell me, how to do it correctly?

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if it works for you so it will also help for other developers. Happy coding!

Comment: Hi! Is my question above too simple or not understandable or can I improve it any way to make it more understandable?

Comment: Seems there is no issues in that and it should work fine.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)`  the post var so you can check clearly what is going on

Comment: hmm... that works fine for one object as you described. However, if I wanted to add a second object as described in comment 1, the second one is not posted. Is it not possible to post 2 objects? I could of course merge them in javascript, but I would prefer to keep them as two objects...

Comment: See i have updated the answer, you can access them in PHP like
`$_POST['data']['myObject1']` and `$_POST['data']['myObject2']`

Comment: thank you for the info... however, I encounter a strange problem if I do that. The second object only contains language info, e.g.:
_myObject2['lContinue'] = 'continue'_
Sometimes the literal is very long (e.g. 'lWarningMessagePage7Calculation2'). If I now try to send this object as mentioned above, I encounter a different problem: Only the first 15 elements are copied (or at least logged to the console), equaling approx. 800 characters. I checked if there is a limitation to JSON but my object is far from those limits... so why do I get this error?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: There could be some other issues, not sure json limit exceeds, Check request on developer tools -> network tab (pressing F12) , Check the request param actually you are sending the whole JSON.

Comment: I think you should accept the answer, It solved your problem you mentioned in the question and still am happy to help you further even you accepted the answer

Comment: I finally found the solution: The object was simply too large at one time and this lead to the mentioned problems. I now only select the variables I actually need and now it works!
What I want to do in php is to create a pdf via fpdf which is actually quite easy. However, with this new **post** structure, the pdf will not be created, even if I only create the absolute minimalistic file:
<?php
_require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>_
Can you explain why?

Comment: it might be important for other users as well to highlight, that jQuery.post is slightly different compared to form .post. One has to keep that in mind for further use of the data. In my case, I try to create a pdf output via fpdf and that seems not to work with jQuery.post. (see here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47547758/post-of-an-object-and-pdf-output-via-fpdf/47547849#47547849). So in many cases, jquery.post would not be the preferred method, instead the creation of a form with hidden fields might do the trick if only normal objects are concerned.

Comment: Great find ! happy coding mate

Comment: I would like to refer to the larger question, which shows the overall problem [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47547758/post-of-an-object-and-pdf-output-via-fpdf/47569247#47569247) and my solution, which works without jQuery/Ajax and thus allows easy pdf creation via fpdf.
Cheers!

Comment: Awesome dude! :+1: