# Post of an object and pdf output via fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, post, fpdf

Good morning! I am trying to send a large object from JavaScript to php, to generate a PDF output via FPDF.
So far, you helped me to post the object with the following snippet:

```
jQuery.post('output.php', {
    data: {
        myObject:myObject
    },
}, function(data) {

    console.log(data);

});
```

That works, I can access the data in php. However, this method seems to prohibit a pdf output. Even if I have nothing in my php code than the 'Hello World' example of fpdf, I do not get a pdf-file:

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

I think this might be due to the function(data){console.log(data)}, but so far I haven't found out how to fix that.

**EDIT ------------------**

If the "post" call is done like that:

```
post("output.php");
```

everything works fine...

**EDIT ------------------**

**EDIT 2 ------------------**

It seems, that this is a general problem of fpdf if you want to create a pdf via jQuery. You can actually find many posts and questions regarding this in SO, once you know what to look for...
However, all those posts then suggest not to use jquery but to transmit the values via a "form"-post. Well - this is what I did to begin with:

```
function post(path, calcdata, method) {
method = method || "post";
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", method);
form.setAttribute("action", path);
form.setAttribute("target","_blank");

for(var key in calcdata) {
        if(calcdata.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "CalculationData["+key+"]");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("value", calcdata[key]);

                form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
}

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
}
```

My problem is however, that I have an object (*calcData*) which contains an array of other objects and I do not know, how I could adapt the code above to correctly post this data... with the jQuery post data transfer is possible but pdf output does not work... if anyone knows a solution for either problem, this would be much appreciated!

**EDIT 2 ------------------**

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, anyone else will need to **post a multidimensional array/object** to php and **create a pdf** from it, here is my solution:

```
for(var key in calcdat) {
        if(calcdat.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if(typeof(calcdat[key]) == 'object' || typeof(calcdat[key]) == 'array'){
                for(var key2 in calcdat[key]){
                    if(calcdat[key].hasOwnProperty(key2)){
                        if(typeof(calcdat[key][key2]) == 'object' || typeof(calcdat[key][key2]) == 'array'){
                            for(var key3 in calcdat[key][key2]){
                                if(calcdat[key][key2].hasOwnProperty(key3)){
                                    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                                    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                                    hiddenField.setAttribute("Name", "CalculationData[" + key + "][" + key2 + "][" + key3 + "]");
                                    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", calcdat[key][key2][key3]);

                                    form.appendChild(hiddenField);                                      
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                            hiddenField.setAttribute("Name", "CalculationData[" + key + "][" + key2 + "]");
                            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", calcdat[key][key2]);

                            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "CalculationData["+key+"]");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("value", calcdat[key]);

                form.appendChild(hiddenField);
            }
        }
}
```

This might not be the most elegant solution, and as displayed it only works for up to 3-dimensional arrays/objects but I think you can get the idea and it is easily extendible. This method lets you **post your object to php without jQuery/Ajax** and thus if you want **to generate a pdf via fpdf**, you can do so without any workaround and you can immediately save / display the pdf on user-side without saving the data on the server.

Hope that helps you to save time, it took me quite a while to locate the problems I had with this (simple) task... Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I might give you solution for `mpdf` if you'd like that:

```
include __DIR__.'..../mpdf.php';
$mpdf=new mPDF(); 

$mpdf->WriteHTML($HTML_CONTENT);
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf','F');
```

so, problem may be similar with `fpdf`, do you see the arguments of `output()` function?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the tip. Unfortunately, I tried all possible output variations already which are for fpdf:
**string Output([string dest [, string name [, boolean isUTF8]]])**
dest can be of the following:
**
    I: send the file inline to the browser. PDF viewer is used if available.
    D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given 
    F: save to a local file with the name given by name
    S: return the document as a string.
**

However, none of that worked... If I only call <output.php> via 'post("output.php")'
that works fine...